Searching in Windows 11 command prompt when symbols
I want to search in Windows 11 command prompt. I first connect to SSH, then I want to search for:
$_POST['wpforms']['id']

or
['wpforms']['id']

It does now work when using...:
grep -Ri "['wpforms']['id']" mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/wpforms*
grep -Ri \$_POST['wpforms']['id'] mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/wpforms*



Have you tried escaping special character?
Eg. \$_POST['wpforms']['id']

Still not working. I have updated my question.

try escaping brackets too, as those have special meaning in regex
grep -Ri "\$_POST\['wpforms'\]\['id'\]" mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/wpforms*

Yes, "$_POST['wpforms']['id']" , is the correct answer! Thanks.
